# Pandas, add new column of count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

To make the question easy to understand, my question is I want to count the number of some variables, and here is my test code and the output

```
>>> g = df_data[['COUNTRY', 'STATE', 'CITY']].groupby(
    ['COUNTRY', 'STATE', 'CITY'])['COUNTRY'].count()
>>> g
COUNTRY    STATE     CITY
2          10.0      0.0           56643
                     40.0             18
                     60.0            596
                     nan             131
           11.0      0.0              20
           12.0      0.0               5
           13.0      0.0               7
Name: COUNTRY, dtype: int64
```

I want the output like this

```
>>> g
COUNTRY    STATE     CITY          COUNT   PERCENT
2          10.0      0.0           56643   56643/number_of_total_record
2          10.0      40.0             18   18/number_of_total_record
2          10.0      60.0            596   ...
2          10.0      nan             131   ...
2          11.0      0.0              20   ...
2          12.0      0.0               5   ...
2          13.0      0.0               7   ...
Name: COUNTRY, dtype: int64
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you want the same value in PERCENT as COUNT ?

Comment: @pyd, of course not. PERCENT is the percentage of COUNT.

Comment: try `g[["COUNTRY","STATE"]]=g[["COUNTRY","STATE"]].ffill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df_data[['COUNTRY', 'STATE', 'CITY']].\
     groupby(['COUNTRY', 'STATE', 'CITY']).\
          size().\
            reset_index(name='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `reset_index()` method.

```
g.reset_index()
```

Comment: what if you don't want to reset the index, but still want a column with a counter?